# Is there a way to have a "default color" with a canvas in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way I can set the default color of canvas objects (lines, rectangles, etc.) without setting each one individually? I know the default color is black, and I basically just want to change that so that everything I subsequently create is, say, green. Is there a way to do this with Tkinter in Python?

Comment: Reading more closely - what is "this point onwards"  (ie if widgets create widgets) or something?

Comment: I'm talking about time, so if I set the default color, I want all canvas objects (lines, polygons etc) to be that default color from then on.

Comment: Err - AFAIK unless you can configure some root object, and override manually what shouldn't be the case, then you'd have to proxy the objects which would be nasty - so errr - I'll bow out of this I'm afraid :(

Comment: When you subclass a `Toplevel` window, simply override/create a default color method that alters the color of objects registered with it. Then, modify your object creation implementation to include some sort of registration process with the window class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to set the default color. However, if you store the color in a variable, you can use that whenever you create new items.

```
self.my_color = "red"
...
self.canvas.create_rectangle(..., fill=my_color)
```

You can also change all objects at once by giving the id "all" to the [itemconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemcget-method) method. For example:

```
self.my_color = "green"
self.canvas.itemconfigure("all", fill=self.my_color)
```

For more on item identifiers (including the special "all" identifier) see [Item Specifiers: Handles and Tags](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers) on [effbot.org](http://www.effbot.org) as well as the [Tags section in the canvas tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html#tags) on [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com)

Comment: Guess I'll have to implement the variable then :) I didn't know about "all", that seems quite interesting. I might use that later, but for now the variable seems simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @walle1357: canvas tags are remarkably powerful. You could, for example, give all circles the tag "circle" and all squares the tag "rectangle", and then change the color of only the circles, or only the squares. You can give items more than one tag, so you could have another tag named "shapes" that apply to all circles and squares (but not embedded windows, for instance).